# Повелительное наклонение гл. Лазить

Tags: наклонение

У Цыбулько в сборнике для подготовки к экзаменам от гл. Лазить форма повелительного наклонения не образуется (написано даже НЕЛЬЗЯ ЛАЗЬ) . Повелительное наклонение образуется только от гл. Лазать (лазай).
А в "Словаре грамматических трудностей"  указана форма лазь.
На что опираться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Опираются всегда на более "дотошный" словарь: Большой орфоэпический словарь русского языка, Словарь трудностей русского языка, Русское словесное ударение - в отличие от толковых и орфографических, которые допускают более одной формы слова.

---

**ла́зить**

ПОВЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ НАКЛОНЕНИЕ

Лицо

Ты  лазь

Вы  ла́зьте

[Словарь трудностей русского языка](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=71)